# How do I write Paragraph.Next(Object) Method to produce 2 "Next Paragraphs" Programmatically (C#) in a MS Word Document after text?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to be able to place 2 paragraphs after text in a MSWord document I am working on. It is all written in a custom compiler setup as an addin in word. Unfortunately I am a C# beginner and I cannot make heads or tails of it anymore.

Will `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph.Next(ref object count);` be able to add even 1 paragraph if added in some way after text? E.g.

Somehow declaring `Paragraph2` as 2 x `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph.Next(ref object count);` and would be used as follows

```
string text = "Hello, World!";
BC.SetThisField(text + Paragraph2);
```

Resulting in (Pilcrows to represent what it would look like with paragraph characters showing):

Hello, World!¶

¶

The link(below) to Microsoft's documentation on this has simply led me down a road of researching `ref`, `object` and their definition of `count` which is apparently 1. I have been unsuccessful in using even the default of what is supposed to be.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.next?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_Paragraph_Next_System_Object__

I have thought, according to similar questions asked on stackoverflow that I should use Paragraphs.Add(Object) Method instead, although I would still be stuck either way.

Comment: If you have the paragraph range then all it takes is .InsertAfter("Hello world").Insertafter("Hellow World2")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's led me to InsertParagraphAfter() and Range. Although it would be great if I knew how to set the range of the text I add at that point in the document as there is a lot of dynamic text ahead of it. I am still learning how to ask the right questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to insert text, followed by two paragraph marks? The simplest C# for that would be:

```
string text = "Hello, World!\n\n";
BC.SetThisField(text);
```

- `\n` or `\r` generates a paragraph mark (ANSI 13) in Word.
- Another possibility is to concatenate `char(13)`.
- There's also `InsertParagraphAfter`, but that requires an additional
  step and a target `Range` object.
- The `Paragraphs.Add()` will insert a single paragraph, but in order
  to insert more than one it would have to be run in a loop and would
  also require a `Range` object as the target.

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph.Next(ref object count);` will *not* insert paragraphs and will return an error if the code tries to perform an action with a paragraph that does not exist. (If code tried to assign text to the paragraph, for example.)

Comment: Hi Cindy, I have only recently come to the conclusion that `Next` will not work - Thank you for confirmation!

With Freeflow's comment on Nov 1, it lead me down the path of looking into `InsertParagraphAfter` and `InsertParagraph`. As you mentioned, these require a `Range` and or `Selection` being defined. Once again down the road of research into those two.

Now, frustrations of knowing how to define a ref object - errors of "(method) used like a (type)" - and trying to create a `Selection` that is at the point of *Insertion* of the *Text* then `InsertParagraph`.

Comment: Addressing the first 2 options - \n or \n classifies as new lien? and adds a carriage return. Same for char(13) - MSWord's "Justify evenly between margines" will stretch even 3 words if followed by a carriage return instead of a `InsertParagraph`. If and when I find the perfect answer I will come back and add it to this question. Learning Learning fun. :)

Comment: @Rynhardtvanvuuren The paragraph formatting is a different issue... I'm not sure why `InsertParagraph` would not result in the described, undesirable behavior - it would be necessary to know the underlying formatting (alignment) of the "starting point" for adding the text - IOW a more detailed [mcve]. And that would also include providing the code in SetThisField. Given the guidelins for using the site, this means asking a new question as it's not "done" to change a question after an Answer has been posted in a way that would invalidate the answer. Handling the formatting is a new topic.

Comment: Using `InsertParagraph` would fit with my desired outcome, apologies for the confusion (Badly written sentence) Thank you for guidance towards setting a new question and the how to. I appreciate it! Thank you.